# Jigomerge Failing in Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins

Could anyone assist me with this Jigomerge error in Jenkins?
I'm sure its probably a config issue but I don't know what config to change.
Google searches showed Jira tickets that were closed with no comments on what fixed the issue.

```
class java.lang.RuntimeException # Failed to reset workspace !
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to reset workspace !
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:54)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
at SvnMergeTool.resetWorkspace(script1000004.groovy:283)
at SvnMergeTool.launchSvnMerge(script1000004.groovy:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1054)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:884)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:704)
at SvnMergeTool.invokeMethod(script1000004.groovy)
at hudson.plugins.jigomerge.JigomergeBuilder.perform(JigomergeBuilder.java:101)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:692)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.build(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:864)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:620)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:462)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1404)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:481)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:238)
Build step 'Perform svn merge with Jigomerge' changed build result to FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding the verbose indicator I looked at the output and noticed that the workspace that Jenkins and jigomerge were trying to update was missing part of the name. This was due to a space in the name of the folder: `My CI build`.
The name with spaces was seen as `/root/.jenkins/My` instead of `/root/.jenkins/My\ CI\ build`.

For this reason, the error that the file or directory did not exist was being returned, failing the merge.